# How to update SQL after 2 minutes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i'm currently trying to create a button on a web page which will essentially reboot a server.

Once the button on the webpage is clicked it will send a request to the url which will reboot the server of which that url originates and also it will `UPDATE` the 3 api servers in my database to `online = 0`, however, once 2 minutes has passed I would like the 3 api servers in my database to be set back to `online = 1`.
If the button is clicked again within the 2 minutes then I would like to show an error message saying `This server has already been rebooted in the last 2 minutes, please try again soon`

This is what I have at the moment but when I click the button it doesn't reboot the server like it should (i have tested this reboot and it does infact work) and `online` isn't updated to `0` in the database.

```
if (isset($_POST['reboot'])){
    $fp = fsockopen("api.example.co.uk", 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: api.example.co.uk\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
        $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `reboot` VALUES(NULL, reboot, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
        $SQLUpdate = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `api` SET `online`= 0 WHERE `name` = 'METHOD1'");
        $SQLUpdate = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `api` SET `online`= 0 WHERE `name` = 'METHOD2'");
        $SQLUpdate = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `api` SET `online`= 0 WHERE `name` = 'METHOD3'");
        $notify = success('Server has been rebooted. Please allow up to 2 minutes for it to get back online.');
    }
    fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

`<form method="post"><button name="reboot" type="submit" class="btn pull-right hidden-sm-down btn-success"><i class="mdi mdi-refresh"></i> Reboot Server</button></form>`

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work".  What _does_ happen? How does that contrast with what you want/expect?  Are you getting errors?  If so, what are they?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: For one thing, you didn't execute any of those queries.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I have updated my answer. Long story short, it doesn't seem to do anything after I click the button when it should at least reboot the server. I have also included my html code for the button.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Oh I see, but surely it should at least reboot the server.. It doesn't even do that. (note: the url api.example.com is replaced with mine)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner... that's what I was thinking... odd that a method named `prepare` is used to execute SQL.. But I don't really know what the `prepare` method of `$odb` is or does. (The `prepare` method of PDO is how we prepare a statement for execution, but I don't see any indication that `$odb` is a PDO database connection.)

Comment: What specifically in here is it that you think is rebooting the server?

Comment: *"But I don't really know what the prepare method of odb does."* - Same here. @spencer7593

Comment: `$odb = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);`

Comment: How often does the server need rebooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i see so many flaws in your process, but if you like to to that, you could do *cof cof* do a sleep($seconds) to wait for this 2 minutes to show the message for your user

or

maybe i didn't understand ... the other, and in my humble opinion, to do the right way, you should create an API in this server (who got the database online setted to 0) and in the server that just went up ou call this API to set the online = 1, got it ?